# Guardar resultado de comando cmd ejecutado desde java en una variable

Tags: java, cmd

Es posible almacenar el resultado de la ejecución de un comando desde java en una variable de tipo string? Lo he intentado de esta manera pero la salida de stdInput.readLine() es siempre NULL, algo estoy haciendo mal. Otra pregunta es si es posible concatenar el resultado de la ejecución del command1 como lo estoy haciendo en command2, introduciendo la variable en medio del string del comando? El código es el siguiente:

```
    public class PDOFinder{

    //PdoFinder constructor
    public PDOFinder(){
    }

    //variables to store device data
    static String webcamPDOName = null;
    static String webcamDeviceID = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        try{

            String output = null;
            String output2 = null;

            String[] command = new String[3];
            command[0] = "cmd.exe";
            command[1] = "/c";
            command[2] = "C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\devcon.exe find =image | findstr USB\\VID*";

            Process process1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(process1.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(input);

            System.out.println("salidaaa: "+stdInput.readLine());

            if((output=stdInput.readLine()) != null){
                webcamDeviceID = stdInput.readLine();
            }

            System.out.println(webcamDeviceID);

            String[] command2 = new String[3];
            command2[0] = "cmd.exe";
            command2[1] = "/c";
            command2[2] = "wmic path Win32_PnPSignedDriver where 'deviceid="+webcamDeviceID+"' get pdo";

            Process process2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command2);
            InputStreamReader input2 = new InputStreamReader(process2.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader stdInput2 = new BufferedReader(input2);

            if((output2=stdInput2.readLine()) != null){
                webcamPDOName = stdInput2.readLine();
            }

            System.out.println(webcamPDOName);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception: "+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Me parece que estás capturando el `stream` de  entrada del proceso en vez de el `stream`  de salida del proceso. Tu quieres guardar en el string lo que salga del programa no lo que entre a el. También creo que deberías capturar los `streams` antes de llamar a `exec`.

Comment: He probado con el metodo OutputStreamReader y no funciona.. sabes como puedo capturar el output? podria capturarlo volcando el resultado del comando en un archivo txt y haciendo un file reader, pero me parece una chapuza, busco algo mas efectivo

Comment: Considera que cada vez que ejecutas `stdInput.readLine` consumes el contenido del stream. Es decir, una vez consumido, ya no lo recuperas. En tu código aparece `stdInput.readLine` 3 veces: 1 en `System.out.print`, otra en el `if` y la tercera que es la asignación. Yo te recomendaría que solo tengas 1, la de asignación, luego comparas si la cadena es nula o vacía y en base al resultado aplicas tu lógica o reglas.

Comment: He intentado esto que me has dicho, la salida es mi version de windows, que no es para nada la salida que tiene el comando cuando lo ejecuto directamente en la consola, pero parece ser que si pierde el valor el stdInput.readLine. Me he quedao como estaba :/

Answer (score 1):

Usando `ProcessBuilder` puedes juntar **stdout** y **stderr** de tu proceso. El método `waitFor()` bloquea la ejecución y espera hasta que el proceso termina, luego devolviendo el resultado (normalmente 0 en caso de terminación normal o >=1 en caso de error).

Puedes usar esta clase para simplificarte la vida:

```
/**
 * @author snolde
 *
 */
public class ProcToString {


    private ProcessBuilder pb;
    private String out=null;
    private Process proc=null;

    public ProcToString(String... cmd){
        pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
        // redirigir stdErr>stdOut
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    }

    // espera a que el proceso termina y devuelve el estado
    public int runProcess() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        proc = pb.start();
        new Stream().start();
        return proc.waitFor();
    }

    // el proceso tiene resultado?
    public boolean hasResult(){
        return !proc.isAlive() && out!=null;
    }

    //devuelve resultado o null
    public String getResult(){
        return out;
    }

    final class Stream extends Thread{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            try {
                while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
                    sb.append(line).append("\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                out=sb.toString();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

lo puedes usar en esta manera:

```
        ProcToString pts=new ProcToString("cmd.exe", "/C", "dir");
        try {
            System.out.println(pts.runProcess());
            if (pts.hasResult()){
                // aquí viene tu resultado
                String resultado = pts.getResult();
                System.out.println(resultado);
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia `getInputStream` por `getErrorStream` de esta forma:

```
InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(process1.getErrorStream());
```

Si devuelve un valor correcto, si lo puedes concatenar en el siguiente comando.

Comment: La misma suerte, devuelve null...

Comment: Al correr tu código en mi PC con el cambio que te digo, me sale esto: salidaaa: El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
null

Comment: Porque la ruta que tu colocas no existe. ¿El comando que utilizas con la ruta, es correcto?

Comment: Si claro, tengo el programa directamente en el escritorio, tengo otra clase que ejecuta un programa en escritorio, es la misma ruta, y funciona, no entiendo que pasa con este, pero ahora veo que tampoco vuelca datos en un archivo de texto desde java, aunque si lo hace si lo hago en linea de comandos, utilizando el mismo comando... Esto es muy raro

Comment: Creo que es un problema de devcon.exe y no del codigo

Comment: Pero con el `getErrorStream` aparece un resultado, por lo menos, con el método anterior no aparecía nada